# Crystal Reports - Turn Month and Year parameter into Start and End Date for Command WHERE clause

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I need to create Month and Year parameters in Crystal Reports and translate those into Start and End Dates for the Command WHERE clause.  I can't use Select Expert with formulas, because the report retrieves a lot of data, so instead I need to limit the data before I pull it into CR.

I have this SQL statement that works for converting a varchar month and year into start and end dates:

```
DECLARE @month varchar(2)
DECLARE @year varchar(4)

set @month= '12'
set @year= '2019'

select 
CAST(cast(@year + '-' + Cast(cast(@month as int) as varchar(20)) + '-01' as datetime) as DATE) as StartDate
,DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, cast(@year + '-' + @month + '-01' as date))), DATEADD(mm, 1, cast(@year + '-' + @month + '-01' as date))) as EndDate
```

My CR Command would then be something like:

```
select * from Table1 where Date between StartDate and EndDate
```

Problem is I can't figure out how to create the parameters in CR to make this work.  When I create them as string data types I get the error:

[image]

I cannot have the users enter Start and End dates either, Month and Year required!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for me was to take the Crystal number parameters and convert them into varchar SQL variables.  The CR parameters are '{?month}' and '{?year} below.

```
declare
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime

set @StartDate = cast(cast({?year} as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast({?month} as varchar(2)) + '-01' as date) 
set @EndDate = DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, cast(cast({?year} as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast({?month} as varchar(2)) + '-01' as date))), DATEADD(mm, 1, cast(cast({?year} as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast({?month} as varchar(2)) + '-01' as date)))

select * from Table1 where Date bewteen @StartDate and @EndDate
```